# Not getting value in Viewstate in asp.net using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate, asyncfileupload

I am using a asyncfileupload control to upload a file there i am taking the path in a view state like this:

```
protected void ProcessUpload(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    string name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(e.FileName); 
    string dir = Server.MapPath("upload_eng/");
    string path = Path.Combine(dir, name);
    ViewState["path"] = path;
    engcertfupld.SaveAs(path);
}
```

Now when i am trying to save that path in a buttonclick event i am not getting the value of viewstate:

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string filepath = ViewState["path"].ToString(); // GETTING NULL in filepath
}
```

In this filepath i am getting null actually i am getting error `NULL REFERENCE EXCEPTION`

What can I do now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the Path value in the **[Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)** object instead of the ViewState, like this:

```
protected void ProcessUpload(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{

    ....
    string path = Path.Combine(dir, name);
    Session["path"] = path;
}
```

Then in the Button Click:

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (Session["path"] != null)
  {
     string filepath = (string) Session["path"];
  }
}
```

Comment: yes i have done this i am getting the result but i still want to know why viewstate didn't work?

Comment: It is enough to use a static variable in the context of the method :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the upload process is not a "real" postback, so the ViewState will not be refreshed client side and won't contain the path upon click on btnUpdate_Click

What you should do is use the OnClientUploadComplete client-side event to retrieve the uploaded file name, and store it in a HiddenField that will be posted on the server on btnUpdate_Click.

Here is a complete example where the uploaded file name is used to display an uploaded image without post-back :

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-image-after-upload-without-page-refresh-or-postback-using-ASP.Net-AsyncFileUpload-Control.aspx

Comment: but i am getting a value in viewstate initially in `ProcessUpload` but whether its postback or not the viewstate should have the value i guess

Comment: @ArindamDas : The value you set in ProcessUpload will not be sent back to the client for being posted back to the server (because this is not a real postback). The server does not store ViewState between postbacks. It is the client which stores ViewState in a (sometime huge) hidden field and post it back to the server. If the postback round-trip process does not occur, the server can not transmit the ViewState to the client. That's why I suggested using client-side event handling