# Persisting variable after AsyncFileUpload call to OnUploadedComplete

Tags: c#, session, viewstate, asyncfileupload

This is a strange one.  So I have an Ajax Toolkit file uploader called AsyncFileUpload located in an update panel.  This AsyncFileUpload control, as soon as you put a file there, begins to upload it and calls the server.  I then store this file as a BLOB and obtain the row ID from a database table using SELECT @@IDENTITY.  So far so good, I now have a row ID and I wish to store it.  I placed it inside a hidden field but when AsyncFileUpload calls OnClientUploadComplete, hidden field is blank!  So I thought "okay, I'll just store it in a ViewState".  Much to my surprise, same thing happened; the viewstate gets cleared.  Finally I had success with using a Session variable.  My question is, why does Session variable work and ViewState or HiddenField do not?

FRONT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function UploadComplete(sender, args) {
        var fileSize = args.get_length();
        if (fileSize > 2000000) {
            alert("Logo size must be smaller than 2MB");
        }

        $("[id*=hfUploadSuccessful]").val("1");
        //Calls a postback and thus lvMembers_PreRender gets executed to get results
        __doPostBack('<%=UpdatePanel1.ClientID %>', null);
    }
</script>

                                    <div id="divClassFileUpload">
                                        <asp:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload1" runat="server" Width="350" CssClass="FileUploadClass floatLeft"
                                            UploaderStyle="Modern"
                                            CompleteBackColor="Lime"
                                            ErrorBackColor="Red"
                                            ThrobberID="Throbber"
                                            UploadingBackColor="#66CCFF"
                                            OnClientUploadError="uploadError" 
                                            OnClientUploadStarted="StartUpload"
                                            OnClientUploadComplete="UploadComplete"
                                            OnUploadedComplete="AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete" />
                                    </div>
```

BACK:

> ```
>     protected void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
>     {
>
>             //hfSelectedArticleId.Value = dt.Rows[0]["ArticleId"].ToString());
>             //ViewState.Add("ArticleId", dt.Rows[0]["ArticleId"].ToString());
>             Session.Add("ArticleId", dt.Rows[0]["ArticleId"].ToString());
>
>         }
> ```

EDIT: Found a similar post that sort of explains it. Thank you everyone!
[Not getting value in Viewstate in asp.net using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642953/not-getting-value-in-viewstate-in-asp-net-using-c)

Comment: Did you forget to make the field static?

Comment: not sure I follow, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Well the variable you're assigning the value to is obviously not retaining its value after the operations have finished. You assigned it to a Session variable, which is completely independent of the code you're executing; therefore it is retained. If you were to use a `static` field somewhere and assign it to that, it should store its value regardless of your code finishing its execution (and possibly disposing itself afterwards, who knows?).