# Why does not the CommandArgument of a button inside a ModalPopupExtender with AsyncFileUpload work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, button

I've been trying for a while to find out the reason why the CommandName of a button does not work, in truth I always throw it empty when entering the onCommand event and even onClick of the same button despite putting the property with a value, the strange of the case is that I can not modify the property and putting the property CommandName works without problem the first time, however it is impossible for me to modify its value.

To start I have a ModalPopupExtender together with a Panel which has a series of TextBox and an AsyncFileUpload with a series of buttons, it is necessary to bear in mind that I am working on an ASPX form, son of a MasterPage:

```
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpEditUser" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnEditUser" TargetControlID="lbShowEditUser"
    CancelControlID="lbCloseEditUser" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
    <Animations>
        <OnShown>
            <FadeIn Duration="0.40" Fps="30" />
        </OnShown>
        <OnHiding>
            <FadeOut Duration="0.40" Fps="30" />
        </OnHiding>
    </Animations>
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Label ID="lbShowEditUser" runat="server" Text="" style="display:none;"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="lbCloseEditUser" runat="server" Text="" style="display:none;"></asp:Label>  

<asp:Panel ID="pnEditUser" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">
                Modify User
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upEditUser" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>

                <p>Message</p>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txtEditUser">Code</label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditUser" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ClientIDMode="Static" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txtEditNameUser">Name</label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditNameUser" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ClientIDMode="Static" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upX" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                        <label class="">CV User</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <label class="input-group-btn">
                                <span class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Upload<cc1:AsyncFileUpload ID="fuCVUser" runat="server" class="form-control" style="display:none;" ClientIDMode="Static" OnUploadedComplete="fuCVUser_UploadedComplete"  />
                                </span>
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly disabled>
                        </div>

                        <span class="help-block">
                            <div class="form-inline">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnDownloadCVUser" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" ClientIDMode="Static" CommandArgument="Test" OnCommand="btnDownloadCVUser_Command" Text="Download" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>

                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upControlsEditUser" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnCloseEditUser" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CausesValidation="true" Text="Close" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" OnClick="btnCloseEditUser_Click" aria-hidden="true" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnEditParticipant" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CausesValidation="true" Text="Update User" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" OnClick="btnEditUser_Click" aria-hidden="true" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Event onCommand:

```
protected void btnDownloadCVUser_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
   string x = e.CommandArgument; <- (this value is always "")
}
```

To get out of doubt, I decided to put the "btnDownloadCVUser" control out of the Panel

```
............
         </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Button ID="btnDownloadCVUser" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" ClientIDMode="Static" CommandArgument="Test" OnCommand="btnDownloadCVUser_Command" Text="Download" />
```

This worked successfully on the CommandArgument, that is, I could see its assigned value on the label and manage to modify its value.

I tried to put UpdatePanel together with the AsyncFileUpload in such a way that it encloses the "from-group" with the triggers but I keep presenting the same problem. It's very strange because I have a button that does exactly the same thing but it's NOT in a MomalPopupExtender

Why does this happen?
Does ModalPopupExtender or AsyncFileUpload have something to do with the problem?
Does the level of the "form-group" have anything to do with it?

So far the only lifeguard I have is to use ViewState, but I'm still intrigued by the reason that causes my problem :(

**Update 01:**
I have noticed that the reason seems to be the method with which I load the files (AsyncFileUpload), apparently if I try to change a variable for this it turns out that it is as if I did not, but it allows me to upload the files without problem. Is there any solution?

```
    private int a = 0;

    protected void fuCVUser_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
       a = 10; < - The value changes to '10' but if I enter the event of another button of the ModalPopupExtender the value is still '0'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After seeing this question:

**[Persisting variable after AsyncFileUpload call to OnUploadedComplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580602/persisting-variable-after-asyncfileupload-call-to-onuploadedcomplete)**

I have come to the conclusion that it is enough to use a static global variable or Session :)

Apparently the AsyncFileUpload method works with static variables which could justify the problem with CommandArgument